# How to submit different value in same field for each user

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario in which user logon into system and submit some entry , but as system does not allow to submit duplicate records , i need to change on of filed value .

How this can be done , an sample code will be much more helpfull.

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of options, feel free to choose the one which suits you best:

- [__threadNum()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function - returns current user number, i.e. 1 for first user, 2 for second, etc.
- [__Random()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function - returns a random number in the given range
- [__time()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function - returns current timestamp in the different formats
- [__UUID()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) function - returns random (type 4) [UUID structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29) - probably the most "unique" option

You can use functions **anywhere** in your test plan, i.e. directly as a parameter value.

[image: UUID]

See the following references:

- [Function helper dialog](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) - a tool which helps to generate correct JMeter Function Syntax
- [JMeter Functions and Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper)
- [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii)

Answer (score 0):

you can map columns of a csv file with [CSV_Data_Set_Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) by setting variables names to : user,pwd...

after that you can use them to logon like this '${user}'